# How to replace "\" with "/" in python? i'm getting an EOL error

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i replace ("\") with ("/") in python?

```
a = ("Hello/World")
b = a.replace("/","\")
print(b)
```

i was expected that i'll successfully replace but i'm getting an error EOL error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = ("Hello/World")
b = a.replace("/","\\")
print(b)
```

Output:

```
Hello\World
```